# Show Password jQuery plugin changes length of password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Downloaded the [showPassword jQuery plugin](http://www.prothemer.com/blog/research-and-development/new-jquery-plugin-targeting-usability-for-password-masking-on-forms/) that enables a check box to mask and unmask a password field.  Functionality works as expected but when the check box is checked it changes the password field size back to default.  Unchecking the check box makes the password field size switch back to whatever is specified in the HTML (35 in my case, 20 is default).

The demo that comes in the plugin download does the exact same thing if you add a size to the password field HTML, so it's definitely a problem with the plugin's code and not my HTML.  Unfortunately my limited knowledge of Javascript/jQuery is not enough to diagnose why this plugin changes the password field length based on the status of the check box. Below is the entire code for the plugin, thanks a lot.

```
;(function($){
$.fn.showPassword = function(ph, options){

    var spinput = $(this);

    $.fn.showPassword.checker = function(cbid, inid){
        $('input[id="'+cbid+'"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr('checked')){
                $('input.'+inid).val(spinput.val()).attr('id', spinput.attr('id')).attr('name',spinput.attr('name'));
                $('input.'+inid).css('display', 'inline');
                spinput.css('display', 'none').removeAttr('id').removeAttr('name');
            }else{
                spinput.val($('input.'+inid).val()).attr('id', $('input.'+inid).attr('id')).attr('name', $('input.'+inid).attr('name'));
                spinput.css('display', 'inline');
                $('input.'+inid).css('display', 'none').removeAttr('id').removeAttr('name');
            }
        });
    }

    return this.each(function(){
        var def = { classname: 'class', name: 'password-input', text: 'Show Password' };
        var spcbid = 'spcb_' + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000);
        var spinid = spcbid.replace('spcb_', 'spin_');
        if (spinput.attr('class') !== '') { var spclass = spinid+' '+spinput.attr('class'); }else{ var spclass = spinid; }
        if(typeof ph == 'object'){ $.extend(def, ph); }
        if(typeof options == 'object'){ $.extend(def, options); }
        var spname = def.name;
        // define the class name of the object
        if(def.classname==''){ theclass=''; }else{ theclass=' class="'+def.clasname+'"'; }
        // build the checkbox
        $(this).before('<input type="text" value="" class="'+spclass+'" style="display: none;" />');
        var thecheckbox = '<label><input'+theclass+' type="checkbox" id="'+spcbid+'" name="'+spname+'" value="sp" />'+def.text+'</label>';
        // check if there is a request to place the checkbox in a specific placeholder. 
        // if not, place directly after the input.
        if(ph == 'object' || typeof ph == 'undefined'){ $(this).after(thecheckbox); }else{ $(ph).html(thecheckbox); }
        $.fn.showPassword.checker(spcbid, spinid);
        return this;
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this plugin is doing is adding a hidden input field next to the password field.  When the box is checked, the value is copied from one field to the other, and the password field is hidded, and the added field is shown.

You need to add a size to both the password field, and the newly added field.

The added input fields have a class of `spin_xxx` (where xxx is a random number).  So, something like this should work:

```
$('#passwordField').prev('input[class^="spin_"]').width(35);
```

Run this line *after* calling `.showPassword`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this functionality yourself with the following:

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() {
    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked'))
        $('#password-field').attr("type", "password");
    else
        $('#password-field').attr("type", "text");
});
```

Comment: You can't actually change the type attribute of an input field.  http://jsfiddle.net/SZFng/

Comment: Fair enough, then I would have a textbox appear at the same position with the value of the password within...

Comment: That's kinda what this plugin does.  It adds another input, the checkbox toggles that input and the original password input.